# Client-Side validations don't work if unobtrusive library is not loaded on every view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation, unobtrusive-javascript

On my ASP.Net MVC Web application, I am loading the following scripts on the _Layout.cshtml file:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/respond.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/toastr.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/easyResponsiveTabs.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")
```

Everything looks good until my first Post, that's when things get messy. When I post (via ajax) a form with client-side validations (for instance: an empty textbox marked as required) I do not see any validation error and the form is submitted to the server with errors on it.

However, if I call the last script once again: 
`@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")`
on every view with a form inside of it, everything works like a charm.

Do you have any idea about what might be happening? I believe I should not be forced to include the script back again on every partial view with a form I want to post...

Comment: Do you have other scripts in the views, for example another copy of `jquery-{version}.js` that might be 'wiping out' scripts in the layout

Comment: @StephenMuecke, no, not at all.

Comment: How are you typically posting - by handling the forms `.submit()` event, or just a buttons `.click()` event (in which case are you calling `$('form'.valid();`)?. And are any of these forms being loaded dynamically into the page using ajax (in which case are you re-parsing the validator)?

Comment: That was it @StephenMuecke! $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);